# Can we access spring services outside the web application?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, analytics, spring-remoting

We use spring 4.3 and spring boot version 1.5 in our web application. For (product) analytics purposes we want to read the metadata of our product which is persisted in an RDBMS store (Oracle). Our application uses spring framework to define services that access the database through hibernate (jpa). These services **add business logic** to the data and return the response to the UI layer.

For analytics purposes we want to read the product metadata which involves mashing up calls to various spring based services. We don't want to add this logic inside the application to avoid any code changes to the application code and get affected by it's release cycle. We want a quick way to fetch the metadata from outside the application. Defining REST based api's for these spring services is also not an option. The analytics application needs to fetch this metadata from multiple application deployments(for different customers) which are on different software versions.

Is it possible to call spring based services from another application?

Thanks.

Comment: what are the integration option? if rest an ws in general are off the field it is probably easier to create a common lib shared between the 2 projects

Comment: The analytics application is suppose to collect metrics from multiple customer deployments who would be on different versions. Hence common set of libs may be difficult

Comment: IMHO, a REST interface would be a robust and portable way to access business data. It would even be easy to restrict access to the REST URL from the analytics application with a simple proxy configuration. But Spring has also offered JMX integration at least since version 3, and more recent versions also offer RMI.

Comment: @SergeBallesta - I understand that REST is robust but exposing api's for every metric would be time consuming since it binds to the application code and release cycle. Do you have experience with spring remoting? The initial overview indicates that it would require code modifications (exposing beans) but that looks like one time activity and that should be fine. Any comments on spring remoting are appreciated.

Comment: Sorry I have never used RMI. I have already used JMX by instrumenting some beans, but I mainly used that in supervisor tools (what JMX is aimed at) so I am unsure whether it is or not an appropriate tool for your requirement. But I do not really agree that REST should be very time consuming. The idea would be to have a thin layer over the relevant beans from the service layer. Simply **you** know your architecture details while **I** don't so my advice may not be relevant ;-)